# Quicker way than onLoadResource to inject javascript into a webview?

Tags: java, android

Parts of an Android webview url have already fired by the time onLoadResource is activated. The delay is minimal but can be clearly seen...

```
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
  injectScriptFile(webview, "hello.js");
  super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}
```

Is there a way to inject javascript into the webview before anything in the body tag renders?

Answer (score 0):

if overriding the webViews `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't do the trick, i think the earliest way to inject javascript into your webView is by annotating an injecting method as a `JavascriptInterface` so it can be called from the website you are loading